# Rails 6 - @font_face not working on other computers in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass, font-face, production-environment

Beginner here!

I've just pushed my first project live to Heroku and am running into a problem regarding fonts on the production server. On my computer, the fonts are able to display absolutely fine, however when viewing from other computers the font turns to browser defaults.

I've found a couple of other posts facing this issue and have felt like I have tried all solutions.

I've tried serving the fonts by directly adding them to public/assets/fonts/my-font.ttf. As well as serving them through the pipeline adding the following lines into application.rb:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app","assets","fonts")
config.assets.precompile << ["*.svg", "*.eot", "*.woff", "*.ttf", "*.woff2"]
```

With regards to my SCSS I have tried using:

```
    url('../fonts/my-font.otf') format('otf');
#or
    font-url('/my-font.otf') format('otf');
#or
    asset-url('/my-font.otf') format('otf');
```

The fonts I am using are Gilroy and Raleway both of which are web-fonts that should be compatible with all browsers through @font_face.

I will share the state of my current files and would love any guidance at all!!

application.scss

```
    /*
     * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
     * listed below.
     *
     * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
     * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
     *
     * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
     * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
     * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
     * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
     *
     *= require_tree .
     *= require_self
     */
    
    // Stylesheet for NavBar & Universal Classes
    
     @import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
     @import "a_base/*";
     @import "b_layout/*";
     @import "c_components/*";
     @import "d_responsive/*";
```

app/assets/stylesheets/a_base/01_font_family.scss

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'gilroy-light';
  src: url('gilroy-light.otf') format('otf');
  src: url('gilroy-light.woff') format('woff'), url('gilroy-light.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: light;

  font-family: 'gilroy-extrabold';
  src: url('gilroy-extrabold.otf') format('otf');
  src: url('gilroy-extrabold.woff')  format('woff'), url('gilroy-extrabold.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: extrabold;

  font-family: 'raleway-bold';
  src: ('raleway-bold.ttf') format('ttf');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: bold;
}
```

public/assets includes all the fonts with fingerprints e.g. gilroy-extrabold-59d834ebcb219368afb4b9ec2acbacf985877c30d87d1da47367a59ee99d511e.woff2

Should also add when viewing Chrome Dev Tools -> Network -> application.css
I can see that it is being served as I would imagine e.g.

```
src: url("/assets/gilroy-light-e9cb24bdf5f46693d31db8989bb279e2704c83170fe0fc1ab73c2f8be54a8af9.otf") format("otf");
```

But the fonts simply aren't working.

Would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

So I think I solved it. It was mainly down to my SCSS. My @font-faces should have been written as.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'gilroy-light';
  src: font-url('gilroy-light.otf') format('otf');
  src: font-url('gilroy-light.woff') format('woff'),
  asset-url('gilroy-light.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: light;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'gilroy-extrabold';
  src: font-url('gilroy-extrabold.otf') format('otf');
  src: font-url('gilroy-extrabold.woff') format('woff'),
  asset-url('gilroy-extrabold.woff2') format('woff2');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: extrabold;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'raleway-bold';
  src: font-url('raleway-bold.ttf') format('ttf');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: bold;
}
```

It was only when I checked Safari on my computer where I noticed that the fonts weren't appearing correctly in both production and development. This led me to start thinking that the problem was infact something to do with my SCSS as opposed to Rails's compiling.

Hope this can help someone else out there who finds themself stuck!!